# Can't add data from request with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have this function:

```
public function store(Requests\OfferRequest $request)
    {

            $offer = new Offer($request->all());

            Auth::user()->offer()->save($offer);

            $maxoffer =  Maxoffer::where('article_id', $request->input('article_id'))
                        ->where('start', $request->input('start'))->get();

   if($maxoffer == null)
    {
      Auth::user()->maxoffer()->create($request->all());
    }
    else
    {
      if($maxoffer->price < $request->input('price'))
      {
        $newOffer = Auth::user()->maxoffer()
                    ->where('id', $maxoffer->id)
                    ->update(['price'=>$request->input('price')]);
      }
    }

        Alert::success('Offer is succesfully added!', 'Good job!')->persistent("Close");

        return Redirect::back();

    }
```

but I can't add data because I got this:

> ErrorException in OffersController.php line 63: Undefined property:
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$price in
>   OffersController.php line 63 at HandleExceptions->handleError('8',
>   'Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$price',
>   'C:\wamp\www\bidbook\app\Http\Controllers\OffersController.php', '63',
>   array('request' => object(OfferRequest), 'offer' => object(Offer),
>   'maxoffer' => object(Collection))) in OffersController.php line 63

What is the problem here?

Comment: what result dd($maxoffer)?

Comment: null ....................... but why, what is wrong with : $maxoffer =  Maxoffer::where('article_id', $request->input('article_id'))
                        ->where('start', $request->input('start'))->get();

Comment: and what result dd($request->all());

Comment: array:5 [▼
  "_token" => "c8RwNaQY1smgPAMDmjCx8VP396RjemnVOoewHaqb"
  "article_id" => "1"
  "key" => "On6IH0PBQRewsOukcZkcdzsriqid5R"
  "start" => "02/16/2016 12:00 am"
  "price" => "61.00"
]

Answer (score 1):

The following returns a collection:

```
$maxoffer =  Maxoffer::where('article_id', $request->input('article_id'))
                    ->where('start', $request->input('start'))
                    ->get(); // Returns a collection
```

So you get the error. Just change the `get` to `first` for example:

```
$maxoffer =  Maxoffer::where('article_id', $request->input('article_id'))
                    ->where('start', $request->input('start'))
                    ->first(); // Returns a single Eloquent Object
```

Now, this will return a single `Eloquent Model` object and will work if any model was found.

Comment: The problem is becouse my $request->input('start') is 2016-02-02 12:00 am and start from database is 2016-02-02 00:00:00 ... How to solve this problem? To convert with carbon  $request->input('start')?

Comment: What is your datatype for the field, hope it's timestamp.

Comment: I also try to make input(start) = 2016-02-02 00:00:00 but again dont work, just return me result NULL

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $maxoffer =  Maxoffer::where('article_id', $request->['article_id'])
                    ->where('start', $request->['start'])->get();
```

Comment: hm, no, that is the same but then I get collection not array - FatalErrorException in OffersController.php line 54:
syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'

Comment: This answer doesn't explain what you think is wrong and why your change would fix it. Additionally, it introduces syntax errors, which definitely won't fix the issue.